# How to remove full exception class when raising an error in python

Tags: python, exception

When I raise an exception in python:

```
raise Exception('exception message')
```

I get: `("<type 'exceptions.Exception'>", 'exception message')`

How do I change it to: `('Exception', 'exception message')` only?

Comment: Where do you get that?

Comment: That is the message that is being returned in the logs. Basically I just want the quotations and <> to be removed.

Comment: What logs are those?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of all your code